# Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading

Tags: upgrade, updates

try to use this guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-to-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa

I run `sudo do-release-upgrade`

and it tells me `Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.`

I've tried updating and upgrading and rebooting a bunch of times, and it still just says this error.

`sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`

```
root@lospec-stage-pre-gallery-beta-update-s-2vcpu-2gb-nyc3-01:~# sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [99.8 kB]
Hit:2 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:3 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
Hit:5 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_16.x xenial InRelease
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:7 https://repos.insights.digitalocean.com/apt/do-agent main InRelease
Hit:8 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu xenial-infra-security InRelease
Ign:9 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/4.0 InRelease
Hit:10 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu xenial-infra-updates InRelease
Ign:11 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/4.2 InRelease
Hit:12 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/4.0 Release
Hit:13 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/4.2 Release
Fetched 99.8 kB in 2s (48.0 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libllvm3.8
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following packages have been kept back:
  cloud-init
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

`apt policy cloud-init`

```
root@lospec-stage-pre-gallery-beta-update-s-2vcpu-2gb-nyc3-01:~# apt policy cloud-init
cloud-init:
  Installed: 0.7.9-90-g61eb03fe-0ubuntu1~16.04.1
  Candidate: 21.1-19-gbad84ad4-0ubuntu1~16.04.2
  Version table:
     21.1-19-gbad84ad4-0ubuntu1~16.04.2 500
        500 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
 *** 0.7.9-90-g61eb03fe-0ubuntu1~16.04.1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.7.7~bzr1212-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

`apt-get dist-upgrade`

```
root@lospec-stage-pre-gallery-beta-update-s-2vcpu-2gb-nyc3-01:~# sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libllvm3.8
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following security updates require Ubuntu Pro with 'esm-infra' enabled:
  libpam0g libgssapi3-heimdal libxdmcp6 libpcre16-3 perl-base libpolkit-gobject-1-0 libdjvulibre-text libcroco3 libwebp5 libdns-export162 fuse libcomerr2 python2.7-dev libjpeg-turbo8-dev libisccfg140 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libwind0-heimdal uuid-runtime linux-headers-generic libfdisk1 libpcre3-dev libsasl2-modules-db linux-libc-dev vim-common libcurl3 gnupg-agent libldap-2.4-2 libpam-modules openssl ruby2.3 libxslt1-dev byobu libc6-dev imagemagick libpam0g-dev ntfs-3g git-man libsystemd0 libexpat1-dev libgd3 libheimntlm0-heimdal libksba8 libgs9 dbus python2.7-minimal libmount1 tcpdump snapd libsqlite3-0 libxrender1 libicu55 binutils libmagickwand-6.q16-2 squashfs-tools bind9-host libvpx-dev e2fsprogs zlib1g libcgraph6 libavahi-common-data dnsutils libgmp10 perl-modules-5.22 libavahi-common3 libpython2.7 libncurses5 python2.7 dnsmasq-base libheimbase1-heimdal libc6 util-linux libpython3.5 python3.5 libgmp-dev open-vm-tools git openssh-sftp-server python3.5-minimal libsepol1 libpolkit-agent-1-0 libisc160 libpython2.7-dev udev locales libpcre32-3 passwd libsasl2-2 zlib1g-dev libklibc libpam-runtime e2fslibs isc-dhcp-common libncursesw5 libgmpxx4ldbl libx11-6 libexpat1 libudev1 libvpx3 rsyslog libwebpdemux1 libpng12-dev libtiff5-dev dirmngr libss2 mount libperl5.22 libaspell15 apport gdisk libblkid1 dpkg imagemagick-6.q16 libtiff5 libmagickcore-6.q16-2-extra libisc-export160 busybox-static libc-bin man-db libsasl2-modules libtinfo5 libruby2.3 python3-apport libxi6 libxmlsec1-openssl libjbig2dec0 libpcre3 libfuse2 linux-virtual libfreetype6-dev tar systemd-sysv libcurl4-openssl-dev libuuid1 libxdmcp-dev libgcrypt20 libxml2-dev liblwres141 libhcrypto4-heimdal libglib2.0-bin vim-runtime liblz4-1 gpgv ubuntu-core-launcher libncurses5-dev vim libpam-systemd libtinfo-dev libcdt5 distro-info-data xz-utils ncurses-term libglib2.0-dev ghostscript libpathplan4 systemd libsmartcols1 login libsepol1-dev libssl-dev libxfixes3 libssl-doc libpolkit-backend-1-0 libwebpmux1 ncurses-bin libpam-modules-bin openssh-server libx11-data ghostscript-x aspell libgvpr2 libopenexr22 unzip openssh-client libmagickcore-6.q16-2 sosreport libgs9-common bsdutils linux-headers-virtual libgraphite2-3 libdns162 libx11-dev libjpeg-turbo8 libx11-doc libglib2.0-data ncurses-base gnupg2 bash policykit-1 libdjvulibre21 libc-dev-bin libxml2 libwebp-dev webp libpython2.7-minimal multiarch-support cpio libroken18-heimdal libfreetype6 ca-certificates libicu-dev perl rsync vim-tiny imagemagick-common libasn1-8-heimdal libzstd1 libisccc140 libkrb5-26-heimdal cron linux-image-virtual libpython3.5-stdlib libbind9-140 gzip python3-jinja2 libtasn1-6 gnupg libgvc6 icu-devtools libpcrecpp0v5 libcairo2 libcupsimage2 libpython2.7-stdlib liblzma5 libpython3.5-minimal libavahi-client3 curl libdpkg-perl libhx509-5-heimdal isc-dhcp-client klibc-utils graphviz python3-problem-report libpng12-0 libglib2.0-0 liblzma-dev libxmlsec1 uidmap libcurl3-gnutls libx11-xcb1 libtiffxx5 libperl-dev libgd-dev libxslt1.1 libssl1.0.0 dpkg-dev tzdata busybox-initramfs
Learn more about Ubuntu Pro for 16.04 at https://ubuntu.com/16-04
The following packages have been kept back:
  cloud-init
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

I uninstalled `cloud-init`, then tried `sudo do-release-upgrade` again. It started to work, but at the end i got this:

```
Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done

Invalid package information

After updating your package information, the essential package
'ubuntu-minimal' could not be located. This may be because you have
no official mirrors listed in your software sources, or because of
excessive load on the mirror you are using. See /etc/apt/sources.list
for the current list of configured software sources.
In the case of an overloaded mirror, you may want to try the upgrade
again later.


Restoring original system state

Aborting
```

Comment: did you do `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` to *install all available updates*? Did this show any errors? If so, those need to be fixed before `do-release-upgrade` will work. [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1437914/edit) your question to add the errors that `apt upgrade` returns.

Comment: yes, ive added the output to my post. i do not see any errors

Comment: xenial = Ubuntu 16.04 which is out of standard support for a long time now. You may keep using it with ESM but questions about it are still off-topic here and in any case you can't release upgrade directly to 20.04, you'll need to do it from 18.04.

Comment: Do you see the following output: "The following packages have been kept back: cloud-init" and "1 not upgraded". That is the problem. Try `sudo apt dist-upgrade` and see if it gets installed.

Comment: @ChanganAuto questions about upgrading to a supported release *are* on-topic, and that's what OP is trying to do.

Comment: The problem is with `cloud-init`, you will have to fix whatever is wrong with your package system that prevents that package from being upgraded.  In future please post terminal output using the {} format, your post is very difficult to read. You could start by posting the output of `apt policy cloud-init`

Comment: added the output from that command @OrganicMarble

Comment: Either comment out the third party repositories, or use the option  –allow-third-party on the do-release-upgrade

Comment: i did `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, the output is above, but it didn't change anything.

what do you mean @ubfan1, comment them out where? I've only been running commands

Comment: One possibility is to uninstall the cloud-init package, then run the release-upgrade.

Comment: You will also need to install `ubuntu-minimal` which may pull in some other packages.

Comment: The repositories are listed in /etc/apt/sources.list and in files in /etc/apt/sources.list.d (rerun sudo apt-get update after changes). The sudo do-release-upgrade --allow-third-party might be easier, but I've never done that.

Comment: doing the 3rd party thing now, seems to be getting farther...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Answer (score 0):

You have 1 not upgraded package after apt update && apt upgrade, it is cloud-init.

```
sudo apt install --only-upgrade cloud-init
```